# wxpython frame on top

Tags: python, wxpython

how can i create a frame that is on top of all the other windows ? also i don't want the frame to be created as an on top window, i want the user to have a button that can be clicked so the frame becomes in on top mode and if it is clicked again then it becomes a normal frame !

i tried using

```
frame= wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Hello',wx.DefaultPosition,(400,500),style=  wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX)

self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
```

but i got an error saying that self.SetTopWindow does not exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I think you might want to look at something like

self.ToggleWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowtogglewindowstyle
and 
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxframe.html#wxframe

Comment: On Windows 7 with wxPython using a wx.PopupWindow, I tried both methods discussed here. Raise() worked, but also gave the popup window focus (undesirable for my application), whereas wx.STAY_ON_TOP did not take focus (this is good for my purposes).

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question but for the record use:

```
self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
```

Answer (score 2):

You definitely want the wx.STAY_ON_TOP style, but I don't know if you can actually apply that style after the frame is already created. Note that if you use that style when creating the frame in its **init**, you will only get that style and you won't have the title bar or buttons. So you should normally do it like this:

`wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is Z-order. Googling wxpython window z got this: http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Bringing-a-Window-to-the-Top-td2289667.html

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#54808c933f22a891c5db646f6209fa4d has this to say:

```
virtual void wxWindow::Raise    (        )      [virtual]

Raises the window to the top of the window hierarchy (Z-order).

Notice that this function only requests the window manager to raise this window to the top of Z-order. Depending on its configuration, the window manager may raise the window, not do it at all or indicate that a window requested to be raised in some other way, e.g. by flashing its icon if it is minimized.

Remarks:
    This function only works for wxTopLevelWindow-derived classes.
```

Comment: thanks everyone but i found something http://groups.google.com/group/wxPython-users/browse_thread/thread/da40922eb7c333cd there are some examples as well

Answer (score 0):

try creating your UI with no wx.STAY_ON_TOP style, then use the following in your class to switch between styles - make sure to call set_style when initialising your UI.

```
def set_style( self, event = None ):
    self.old_style = self.GetWindowStyle()

def stay_on_top( self, event=None ):
    self.SetWindowStyle(self.old_style | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)

def cancel_on_top( self, event = None ):
    self.SetWindowStyle(self.old_style)
```

or if you are using a checkbox

```
def stay_on_top( self, event = None ):
    if self.c_ontop.IsChecked():
        self.SetWindowStyle(self.old_style | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
    else:
        self.SetWindowStyle(self.old_style)
```